# How to use scripted rest api in ServiceNow to import data from an external tool

Tags: integration, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I need to know how I can use scripted rest api to import data from an external tool into a serviceNow table and I need to know if it's an inbound or outbound integration .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with inbound vs outbound.

Inbound means traveling into a place. Example: inbound flights = flights coming to an airport.

Outbound means traveling away from a place: Example: outbound flights = flights coming to an airport

In the examples above, replace "place" with ServiceNow and you have your answer.

To implement the import of data from an external tool into a ServiceNow table you'd use a REST integration inside an IntegrationHub Custom Spoke or Flow Action. Check out this [Exercise: Create an IntegrationHub Spoke](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/sandiego/app_store_learnv2_rest_sandiego_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_sandiego_data_stream_actions/app_store_learnv2_rest_sandiego_exercise_create_an_integrationhub_spoke_and_a_data_stream_action).